# Javascript explicit blocks

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I've learned recently about `explicit block`

```
{
   let foo = 'Hello';
   someFunction(foo);
}
```

I am still not quite sure what it does and how we (developers) can benefit from it.

- Did you used before?
- Do you have a use-case?

Thanks for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `let` (and `const` and `class` and — in strict mode — function declarations) have block scope as of ES2015, you can use a standalone block for private information and just generally for more finely-controlling the scope of variables, where we used to use IIFEs.

That is, here's some ES5 and earlier code that has a private variable, `x`:

```
(function() {
    var x = Math.random();
    console.log(x);
})();
// `x` doesn't exist here
```

`x` is nicely contained to just that IIFE.

Now, with ES2015, we can do the same thing without creating and calling a function:

```
{
    let x = Math.random();
    console.log(x);
}
// `x` doesn't exist here
```

Similarly, since standalone blocks let us control variable scope, we can more explicitly control the content of a closure. For instance, consider this:

```
function doSomething() {
    let retainedInformation;
    {
        let something = /*...get some setup information...*/;
        let anotherThing = /*...more setup information...*/;
        let aThirdThing = /*...even more setup information...*/;
        retainedInformation = /*...something figured out using the above...*/;
    }
    return function() {
        // ...use `retainedInformation`...
    };
}
```

Since `something`, `anotherThing, and`aThirdThing`are all out of scope for the function returned by`doSomething`, they aren't retained by it, just`retainedInformation` is.

But modern JavaScript engines already do closure optimization anyway, and all that setup might well be best off in a function you call from `doSomething` anyway, just on general principle.

---

That said, we'll still probably see lots of IIFEs, because they can return a value. So for instance, if I want a function that uses a private variable, I'll probably do:

```
const foo = function() {
    let privateInfo = 42;
    const foo = () => {
        console.log(privateInfo++);
    };
    return foo;
}();
foo(); // 42
foo(); // 43
```

rather than

```
let foo;
{
    let privateInfo = 42;
    foo = () => {
        console.log(privateInfo++);
    };
}
foo(); // 42
foo(); // 43
```

...although both work.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I have read something about garbage collection, and letting know the engines that it can be thrown away after running ... Keeping things private isn't the only usage of explicit blocks, right?

Comment: @TheBilTheory: Standalone blocks allow you to more finely-control the scope of variables. The primary thing I see that used for is privacy, but of course, it's also true that the sooner a variable goes out of scope, the sooner it can be GC'd.